# My browser is not issuing any cookies from my API

Tags: reactjs, spring, web, cookies, browser

I am trying to use my spring API to issue a HttpOnly Cookie by SET_COOKIE header but my browser is not displaying any cookies. It worked 7 months ago and it also works on my 2 friend's computer now, and doesn't work on mine and on another friend's computer too. It also works on postman perfectly fine.

This is method that issues cookie:

```
@PostMapping("/token")
    public ResponseEntity<Token> token(Authentication authentication) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        AppUser appUser = (AppUser) authentication.getPrincipal();
        Fingerprint fingerprint = fingerprintService.getFingerprint(appUser.userId());
        MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        messageDigest.update(fingerprint.value().getBytes());
        String stringHash = Arrays.toString(messageDigest.digest());


        Instant now = Instant.now();
        long expiry = 1800L;
        Collection<String> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities()
                .stream()
                .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        JwtClaimsSet claims = JwtClaimsSet.builder()
                .issuer("self")
                .issuedAt(now)
                .expiresAt(now.plusSeconds(expiry))
                .subject(authentication.getName())
                .claim("scope", authorities)
                .claim("userId", appUser.userId())
                .claim("fingerprint", stringHash)
                .build();
        Token token = Token.newOf(this.encoder.encode(JwtEncoderParameters.from(claims)).getTokenValue());
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("userFingerprint", fingerprint.value());
        cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
        String cookieString = String.format("%s=%s; HttpOnly", cookie.getName(), cookie.getValue());
        return ResponseEntity.ok().header(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, cookieString).body(token);
    }
```

This is method that posts cookie:

```
const getUser = () => {
    return fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + "users/fromToken", {
        method: "GET",
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + getJwtToken()
        }
    })
}
```

This is method that gets this cookie:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "${app.origin}", allowCredentials = "true")
class UserController { 
...
    @GetMapping("/fromToken")
    ResponseEntity<UserResponseDto> getSingleUser(Authentication authentication){
        return ResponseEntity.of(userService.findAppUserByName(authentication.getName()));
    }
}
```

I tried using 172.27.160.1:8080 instead of localhost:8080.
I tried on mozilla, chrome, edge and opera.
In mozilla I turned off cookie blocking.

Comment: Are you using HTTP or HTTPS? I did blog about how to diagnose cookie problems at https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/